# How to disable cipher CBC on apache 2.4 on centos 7

Tags: ssl, encryption, centos

Halo all,

I would like to disable cipher CBC on apache2.4 because when I did penetration test my SSL configure with kali linux (using ./testssl -U mydomain.com), I got some notification like this picture below. [pentest my ssl configure with testssl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQBxS.png)

I wish there is someone can help me to disable cipher CBC. 
here my configure in **/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf**
SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!kECDH:!aDH:!RC4:!3DES:!CAMELLIA:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!KRB5:@STRENGTH

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **apache server configuration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apache user mailing list, this would give you an A+ on SSL Labs, thus reaching your goal :

```
ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
```

Comment: Thank you for your replied, I've tried, but It doesn't work for me.

Comment: the message: potentially vulnerable, uses cipher block chaining (CBC) ciphers with TLS. check patches

Answer (score 0):

I think he means

> ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DES

the last word should be 'DES' not 'DSS'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).